# Define route from the stops table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to define routes from the `stops`

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
            (stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
             name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
             lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, 
             longi double(10,6)NOT NULL) 



    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes
            (arrivaltimes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            route INT(11) NOT NULL, 
            arrivaltime time NOT NULL,
            stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )
```

I would do it like these:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes
  (
        route_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        route INT(11) NOT NULL

        )
```

and add this line to the `stops` table:

```
route_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_route_id(route_id) REFERENCES routes(stop_id)
```

Is that a possiable solution? And how can I do it?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: you can do it by using "Alter table" command, 
"ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype"

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu: What I am asking here is whether my idea is a good solution or the idea is wrong.

Comment: You can do it like that, everything is based on your stop_id/route_id

Answer (score 0):

Just define the `routes` table first:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes (
    route_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    route INT(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops (
    stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    lat double(10, 6) NOT NULL, 
    longi double(10, 6) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes (
    arrivaltimes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    route INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    arrivaltime time NOT NULL,
    stop_id INT,
    route_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_route_id(route_id) REFERENCES routes(route_id)
    . . .
);
```

Note:  `arrivaltimes` uses `route_id`, not `route`.  Be consistent and always use primary keys for foreign key references.

You can also do it using an `alter table` statement, but defining the tables in order is simpler.